# Why does my Python while loop prevent my tkinter window from opening?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

In a tkinter GUI, I have a few classes, and at the end, a `while` loop. Without the `while` loop, everything works fine, save for the functions in the loop. But whenever I put the `while` loop on the end, the tkinter window didn't open. Here is some of my code:

```
while 1:
    Game['paper'] += Game['totalpps']/10
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

There is a lot I cut out, but I have a Game dictionary that has all the games data. But when the while loop is going, the tkinter window doesn't appear. Even after I put a `time.sleep(5)` before the while loop, the window didn't appear.

Any ideas why?

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am using a raspberry pi, with the Raspbian OS.

Comment: When you call sleep, the application sleeps. That means it can't refresh the window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use after method to prevent main loop from freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just put `root.update()` before the while loop and in the while loop, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Threads can easily solve your problem:

```
from threading import Thread

# All this code must occur before calling window.mainloop()

def loop():
    while 1:
        Game['paper'] += Game['totalpps']/10
        time.sleep(0.1)

Thread(target=loop).start()
```